# Adding array indices in parameter declarations with 'static' leads to error

Tags: c, visual-studio, c99

I want to compile 2 C functions using VS2019 (MSVC 19.24.28314.0):

```
void func1(int array[1]) { }
void func2(int array[static 1]) { }
```

The function 1 was compiled normally, however function 2 could not be compiled, showing errors:

> error C2143: syntax error: missing ']' before 'type'
>
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'type'
>
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'constant'
>
> error C2059: syntax error: ')'
>
> **NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1424~1.283\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe' : return code '0x2'**
>
> **Stop.**

What did I do wrong with the `static` C99 feature?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio does not fully support standard C. This is likely something it omits.

Comment: While this is accepted by gcc, I believe that there is no difference between the two declaration - from a practical point of view, no point adding static to the declaration.

Comment: The Visual Studio compiler only supports C89 and whatever language features also exist in C++. `static` for array sizes in parameter lists is not supported in C++, so the VS compiler doesn't support it

Comment: @dash-o: The declarations are different; Clang will complain if it observes a null pointer passed for an argument that is declared with `static` or if it observes a pointer to too few elements passed.

Comment: I thought Visual Studio mostly supported C99, since VS2015. Here is a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170#c-standard-library-features-1

This is disappointing though the static array declaration doesn't work in VS2019, and it doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere on that page.